# Swiftui - Cannot present Form inside Sheet or FullScreenCover

Tags: swiftui

When using a `Form` on a view and presenting it with either `.sheet` or `.fullScreenCover` the view is never presented and instead memory is quickly gobbled until the app crashes. Removing the form and replacing it with anything else works just fine.

Inside top level view, the sheet or full screen uses:

```
        .fullScreenCover(isPresented: $showProfile, content: {
            NavigationView {
                ProfileNumberView()
            }
        })
```

OR

```
        .sheet(isPresented: $showProfile, content: {
            NavigationView {
                ProfileNumberView()
            }
        })
```

The view it's launching can be as simple as:

```
var body: some View {
    Form {
        Text("TEST")
    }
}
```

Again doing this causes the app to simply gobble up memory until a crash and no view is presented. If I simply remove the `Form` tag, the the view will present as normal. I have also tried embedding the `NavigationView` inside the form view (above the `Form` tag) but to no avail.

Why can I not present a view using a Form in this manner?

Update: I have discovered the source of the issue is when the top level view contains a `List`. If there is no list the screens present just fine, but it seems we cannot present a form within a cover or sheet if the parent has a list in it. Still not clear why that would be the case but commenting out the list and the sheet or fullscreencover worked.

Answer (score 0):

The turned out to be something that was not directly related to the code I posted above. It's worth posting the answer though as I am sure others may run into this. The problem was styling given to the list in order to paint a background with an image. Specifically:

```
UITableViewCell.appearance().backgroundColor = .clear
let imageView = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "gradientBackground"))
imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
UITableView.appearance().backgroundView = imageView
```

This styling of the list for some reason prevents you from presenting a sheet or full screen cover that has a form. Very unclear why and I need this background, so while this particular issue is resolved, the functionality required is not.